# Telerik Radtextbox with round corners in VS2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, radtextbox

I am using a `Radtextbox` control in my vb2013 project. Was trying something new by rounding the radtextbox control. I used this piece of code to accomplish it but didn't worked. How can we achieve rounded corners for a `RadTextbox` control.
[Code]: `Me.RadTextBox1.TextBoxElement.Shape = Telerik.WinControls.ElementShape.`

Comment: Did you find an answer for this?

Comment: No..........................